# Dereferenced Int Value With Lambdas

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to sort and print an `ArrayList` that is sorted by ID.

```
clientArr.sort( (p1, p2) -> p1.getAccount().getID().compareTo(p2.getAccount().getID()) );
for(Client client : clientArr)
    System.out.println(client);
```

I believe my issue is because `p1` and `p2` are expecting objects to be returned, but they are getting `int` values. How would I go about fixing this?

The ArrayList stores Client objects. Client class contains String values (not important in this example) and it creates an instance of an Account object. Within the Account class is stored the int ID value. That's the value I need

Comment: I was trying to use lambdas. @OusmaneMahyDiaw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Integer.compare(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) like,

```
clientArr.sort((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getAccount().getID(), 
                                           p2.getAccount().getID()));
```

Also, your `for-each` loop could be rewritten like

```
clientArr.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ah, using Integer fixed my problem. Thank you.

Could I ask, what would be the benefit of writing the for loop like that as opposed to my way?

Comment: @NickM It's also using lambdas and it would eliminate one line of code. No other reason I can think of.

Comment: You can also create a Comparator for for your Collection::sort method call that does both the Integer::compare call and getter calls for you: clientArr.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getAccount().getId()));

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Gotcha. It's a good way to look at it, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Since `clientArr` is, despite its name, a `List` (otherwise you couldn’t call `sort` on it), `Stream.of(clientArr)` should be `clientArr.stream()`, but it would be even simpler to use just `clientArr.forEach(System.out::println);`. The way you have written it, it creates a single element stream, in other words, is equivalent to `System.out.println(clientArr);`, which happens to also print the list contents, but in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this stuff in just one go and in a functional way that Java8 suggests -

Use **sorted** of Stream API and provide a comparator as the method reference.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ComparingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> mTestList = new ArrayList<>();
        mTestList.add(new Test(10));
        mTestList.add(new Test(1));
        mTestList.add(new Test(5));
        mTestList.add(new Test(4));
        mTestList.add(new Test(2));
        mTestList.add(new Test(8));
        mTestList.add(new Test(7));

        mTestList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getId)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class Test {
    public int id;

    Test(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(getId());
    }
}
```